# Is Hong-Sau an ancient Sanskrit mantra?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

Read an article on meditation [here](https://www.ananda.org/meditation/how-to-meditate/) it says:

> Hong-Sau is an ancient Sanskrit mantra (a mantra is a word, syllable,
>   or group of syllables, which can convey spiritual power when
>   pronounced correctly, often with repetition). It means “I am He” or “I
>   am Spirit.” Try to feel that your breath itself is silently making the
>   sounds of Hong and Sau.

My question: Are there any references found in our scriptures about this mantra 'Hong-Sau' ? Never heard about this mantra before. Perhaps it is 'Hamsa'?

Comment: Hamsa(ssoham) does mean the said meaning. It could be a case of bad transliteration.

Comment: You can find more details in autobiography of a yogi by paramahansa yogananda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Try to feel that your breath itself is silently making the sounds of
>   Hong and Sau.

It is quite clear that it is talking about the Hamsa Mantra also known as the Ajapa Japa which everyone does constantly but without any special effort.

There are plenty of excellent references from the Tantras on Hamsa but I'm quoting now from a minor Upanishad.

> The Jeevatma (the soul of the physical individual) is under the
>   control of prana which goes up and down as well as apana. Apana pulls
>   Prana. Prana pulls Apana. He who knows and realizes this mutual pull
>   which is pulling to the top and bottom, understands yoga. 30 **It goes
>   outside with the sound “ha” and goes again inside with the sound “sa”.
>   The beings keeping on chanting this mantra as “Hamsa”, “Hamsa”. 31 The
>   beings always keep on chanting this mantra day and night twenty one
>   thousand and one hundred times. 32  This mantra which is called “Ajapa
>   Gayatri” would give salvation to all yogis. Just a thought of this
>   mantra, would help one get rid of all sins.** 33 There are no practices
>   as holy as this, no chanting which is equivalent to this, and no
>   wisdom equivalent to this and in future also this is not likely to be
>   there. 34 This Ajapa Gayatri which rises from the Kundalani supports
>   the soul. This is the greatest among the sciences of the soul. He who
>   knows this will know the Vedas.

[**From the Yoga Chudamani Upanishad linked with the Samaveda.**](http://www.celextel.org/upanishads/sama_veda/yogachudamani.html)

Ham is Ha+anuswara (or the Bindu) which that website has written as Hang or Ha+ng. So, instead of writing the Bindu as "m" they have used "ng" (Bengalis in particular often do that).

To write Sauh instead of Sa is not wrong too. Sauh is the Parashakti Bija where as Ham (or Haum) is the Shiva Bija. When these two Bijas are combined the Hamsa Mantra is formed.