# What is mantra siddhi?

Tags: mantras

Is mantra siddhi same as ajapa jap? Are we not required to chant that particular mantra after attaining siddhi in it?

Is it about chanting mantras as much lakh times as much there are letters in it?

Also, is 125,000 counts hold any significance?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26566/21353

Comment: See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28353/4732), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40963/4732), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35323/4732).

Comment: @Rickross thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @Rudra you don't seem to be much active these days. I hope everything is alright with you. We are missing the great questions that you used to ask :(

Comment: @Rickross exams coming. Will be free after some months

Comment: Thanks for the response. Okay good luck for the exams :) @Rudra

Answer (score 2):

Well quoting from what I read in "[The Ancient Science of Mantras: Wisdom of the Sages](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35428340-the-ancient-science-of-mantras)" by [Om Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Swami) that defines mantra sadhana & siddhi in nutshell:

> The basic principle of **mantra sadhana** is to practice the utterance of
> a sound with such intensity, fervor and determination, that your whole
> being starts to reverberate with that sound. You become that sound. It
> becomes your sound, your mantra. The one you not only connect with,
> but that transports you to another dimension of consciousness.
>
> Think of **mantra siddhi** as your child made from pure energy. The ten
> samskaras ensure proper upbringing of this child so he is obedient,
> wise, compassionate and competent.
>
> By doing various mantra samskara, we are preparing the mantra to have
> a life of its own. **That’s what siddhi is**.

And the number you stated 125,000 is usually part of the ***purushcharana*** which is basically part of Naimatik Karma.

> After an aspirant has championed the art and routine of practicing
> daily duties with reverence, mindfulness and sincerity, the guru,
> depending on the potential, inclination and readiness of the disciple,
> imparts the detailed instructions on how to invoke the mantra.